# Can kubernetes be used without linux?

Tags: kubernetes

Can kubernetes be used without linux? There is nothing other than this document: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is still very much Linux centric. There is ongoing work to have Windows a more important player in the Kubernetes space but it's all tech previews and early betas AFAIK.

This is one of the most recent news I can find about Kubernetes and Windows from Docker. It's a Tech Preview, https://blog.docker.com/2018/06/kubernetes-on-windows-server-with-docker-ee/ :

> Docker and Microsoft have been working together since 2014 to bring
>   containers to Windows and .NET applications. Today at DockerCon, we
>   share the next step in this partnership with the preview and
>   demonstration of Kubernetes on Windows Server with Docker Enterprise
>   Edition.

It looks like Red Hat is working on Windows support as well, https://blog.openshift.com/red-hat-openshift-and-microsoft-windows-containers/ :

> The Red Hat OpenShift and Microsoft Windows engineering teams have
>   been working on bringing Windows containers to OpenShift for the past
>   several months. The teams publicly committed to the project back in
>   August. Over the course of that time, Microsoft has been working with
>   the Kubernetes community to add the core competencies required to make
>   the project possible. Windows support in Kubernetes is really the
>   first time the upstream project has been extended to support a popular
>   operating system other than the Linux derivatives.

I would recommend that you focus on Kubernetes on Linux for the years to come if you're serious about Kubernetes. Windows support is more a sandbox early stage right now.